# Lost all gnome settings after reboot

Tags: gnome, 17.10, configuration, data-loss

I had my system up and running for about one year (many personalizations I've made to my system) and today my system froze because there was no space left on /home after I restarted the system and freed some space and logged into the os I got a default gnome looking desktop with all the personalizations lost, and I can't change any gnome-related settings now (i.e. background, dock settings, notification settings, ...)

Also, some applications like uGet have lost some settings.

Is it a way to fix this?

I'm running Ubuntu17.10 gnome3.26.2

Comment: Settings like background can't be changed, I'm getting no action when I try to change my background.

Comment: How did you "free some space"? Probably you have deleted (some) config files.

Comment: No i moved my /home/amk/Downloads